# Times New Roman not working after installing ttf-mscorefonts-installer in Debian

Tags: debian, libreoffice

I have installed ttf-mscorefonts-installer to get Times New Roman to work in Libre Office in Debian Stretch. A very weird thing has happened though - Times New Roman is not installed but other fonts are. The font list now only goes down to the letter "O". There is nothing beyond it. Arial and Comic Sans etc are there but nothing beyond "O".

Is there are way to remedy this and get Times New Roman working?

Comment: Guess: Some odd character is messing up the font lists. I'd go hunting for the configuration files where the fonts are stored, e.g. `/etc/fonts` etc. Also look at `fontconfig` and the `fc-*` commands.

Comment: @dirkt thanks again for your help, dirkt. I don't know what caused the issue, but a reinstall through Synaptic fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and in my case reinstalling did not solve it.

Nevertheless, I found another solution.  I searched the `.ttf` files
and found they were stored in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts`. 
Then I just doubled-clicked the `Arial.ttf` file
and it opened a program called "Visor de tipografías"
(tentative English translation: “Typeface viewer” – by [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Visor%20de%20tipograf%C3%ADas))
which had the option "Install" on it. 
I pressed that and it just installed the font. 
I did the same with Times New Roman and it got installed as well.